# Remove C++ char* has point address

Tags: c++

Since I changed my project settings, the boolean value below returns false because in the debugger, value of the char* parameter contains pointer address.  how do i remove this?

I created this simple example to illustrate (i have to keep char* data type) and I can't do pattern matching to remove the pointer address.

```
void Test(char* thisValue) 
{
if (thisValue == "PassingTest")
{
bo = true;
}
else
{
bo = false;
}
}
```

In debugger, I found thisValue = " PassingTest"

Please guide how to let thisValue only contain "PassingTest" as a value and not pointeraddress.

Comment: `bo = (strcmp(thisValue, "PassingTest") == 0);`

Comment: Use strstr or strcmp to check on strings. Either that or dereference (operator *) every char of the string and compare it until you meet a) a different char (false) b) NULL in one of the strings (false) c) NULL in both (true).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `==` operator cannot compare string values in C; it can only compare their pointers.  Use the `strcmp` function to test whether two strings are equal (it returns 0 if they are).

Answer (score 5):

That's how char*s work - they're pointers to characters in memory. If you want a string that supports values you can use `std::string` from `#include <string>`.

Working with char*s, you can use

```
if (strcmp(thisValue, "PassingTest") == 0)
```

and if you're not intending to modify the string contents in your function you can accept `const char* thisValue` rather than just `char* thisValue`.

Answer (score 2):

```
if (thisValue == "PassingTest")
```

This will not work, as `thisValue` is `char*`.

Use `std::string`:

```
if (std::string(thisValue) == "PassingTest")
```

It will work now.

It will be better if you do this:

```
void Test(const std::string & thisValue) 
{
    bo = (thisValue == "PassingTest") ;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have no guarantee that two identical literal strings will reside at same memory address.

If they do then that's an example of "constant folding", which is an optimization that may or may not be done.

So your code has arbitrary result.

To avoid this problem, just use **`std::string`** instead of raw pointers and raw arrays.

Like

```
void test( std::string const& thisValue )
{
    bo = (thisValue == "PassingTest");
}
```

Cheers & hth.,

Answer (score 0):

In C use [`strcmp(3)`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/strcmp.3.html). C++ has nice `std::string` for this.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why is that in C++ the comparison in the `if` block is comparing pointer addresses not `string` values.  To compare the actual `string` values you'll need to use a function like `strcmp` or even better use STL `string` values

```
void Test(const stl::string thisValue) {
  if (thisValue == "PassingTest") {
    bo = true;
  } else { 
    bo = false;
  }
}
```